# Email intent in constant loop

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Ive got my email intent working well as in it posts emails. Im now getting an issue where once I click 'send email' on my custom template, which sets the 'To', 'subject' and 'message' fields of the GMail template it loads fine but then when i click 'send' on the GMail template it loops back to the custom template. As shown:

This is my custom made email template:

[image]

Once 'send email' is clicked then the Gmail template is loaded:

[image]

Once the 'Send' button of the GMail template is cliked it loops back to the custom template and they loop between each other continuously. Hoping someone can give me an idea of how I can stop this looping!

Here is my code with my intent within the 'onClick':

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactsEmail extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

String emailPassed;
String emailAdd;
String emailSub;
String emailMess;
EditText setEmailAddress;
EditText setEmailSubject;
EditText setEmailMessage;
Button btnSendEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.emaillayout);


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if (extras != null) {
    emailPassed = extras.getString("passedEmailAdd"); 
}


setEmailAddress = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailAddress);
setEmailAddress.setText(emailPassed);
setEmailSubject = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailSubject);
setEmailMessage = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.inputEmailMessage);



btnSendEmail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);

btnSendEmail.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onClick(View sendEmailClick) {

    emailAdd = setEmailAddress.getText().toString();
    emailSub = setEmailSubject.getText().toString();
    emailMess = setEmailMessage.getText().toString();

    Intent sendEmailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sendEmailIntent.setType("plain/text");
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] {emailAdd});  
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSub); 
       sendEmailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailMess); 
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmailIntent, "Send mail..."));

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you are doing, but what happens if you call `finish()` at the end of `onClick()`?

Comment: @user1352057 Why you make a separate layout for template.

Comment: @Sam. Many thanks! That was it, i missed on the onFinish() method. If you could answer it then i'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you simply want to call `finish()` at the end of `onClick()`.  This will close ContactsEmail allowing the user to return to a more useful Activity from the GMail app.